# Is it possible to use structures in embedded MATLAB functions?

Tags: matlab, simulink

If yes, what should be the data type specified in model explorer for those parameters.

When trying to make a circular buffer for images I'm getting an error in initialization: `Attempt to extract field <field name> from double`. I have initialized the structure as `uint8`.

Comment: You should show us what you have done. A simple version of the code would be good.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, for example:

```
function y = fcn()
y = [1;2;3;4];
```

To access the structure elements you would then use a demux:[image: simulink model shoing embedded matlab function and a demux with displays]

The default setting for the data type is 'inherited' so it will depend on the following blocks. you may require another type, but note that for a structure the data type is for the *elements* rather than the *outport*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, see more details [in the Simulink doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/structures.html). If you need the structure to either be an input or output, what you would need to do is to create Simulink.Bus object to define the structure (similar to a C typedef).  For internal variables, you should be able to use the standard MATLAB language to create and modify structs.